# select an element that its closest parent with special attribute has special value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select an element that its closest parent with special attribute has special value. For example, in the bellow code I want to select an element that has att2="sp" and it's closest element that has an "att1" attribute, has value equal to "first_div".

```
<div att1="first_div">
    <div att1="sec_div">
        <span att2="sp">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span att2="sp">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery selector like `$('[attr2=sp]')` to access that special attribute and for closest parent use `$('[attr2=sp]').parent()` selector.

Comment: @SachinK yes you are right but if i use .parent(), it will return the parent element but i want the child . for example in my case i want to get <span> as a result not <div>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just a CSS selector that can then obviously be used in jQuery as well.

```
[att1=first_div] :not([att1]) [att2=sp], [att1=first_div] > [att2=sp]
```

should do the trick?

In jQuery terms,

```
var $el = $('[att1=first_div] :not([att1]) [att2=sp], [att1=first_div] > [att2=sp]');
```

EDIT:

OK, looks like the problem might be a bit out of scope for a pure CSS solution after all. This JavaScript bit should finally get your desired result:

```
var $matches = $('[att2=sp]').filter(function() {
    // Get closest parent with 'att1' attribute
    var $closestCandidate = $(this).closest('[att1]');
    // Include in result if a parent with att1 was found, and the att1 value is 'first_div'
    return $closestCandidate.length && $closestCandidate.attr('att1') === 'first_div';
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twmf2atj/3/).

Comment: this is work for me! but i need jquery code. can you convert your selector to jquery mode?

Comment: @pooyan Please note that the original answer had a limitation: an immediate `att2=sp` child of a `att2=first_div` was not matched. For instance `<div att1='first_div'><div att2='sp'></div></div>` would not have matched. I updated the answer to include this case as well.

Comment: tanks for your answer. but i faced with problem :(. your answer did not worked in this : https://jsfiddle.net/twmf2atj/2/

Comment: @pooyan So I see. Updated answer again with a hopefully comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by these way :-

```
$("div[att1='first_div']").find("span[att2='sp']");
```

It may help you.

Comment: if i use .parent(), it will return the parent element but i want the child . for example in my case i want to get <span> as a result not <div>.

Comment: you need child using parent or need child whose parent is specific?

Comment: i think you need child whose parent is specific, let me know if you need these, I will update my answer again.

Comment: yes i want to select child that has special parent( as i mentioned in my question).

Comment: This answer does not consider the requirement that the CLOSEST parent of the `[att2=sp]` with an `att1` attribute must have an `att1` value of `first_div`. `<div att1='first_div'><div att1='second_div'><div att2='sp'></div></div></div>` will erroneously match.

Comment: @HarshSanghani your answer did not work. it will find all child that hav att2='sp'. !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var temp=$('span[att2="sp"]').first().parent().parent();

alert(temp.attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div att1="first_div" id="testing">

<div att1="sec_div">
    <span att2="sp">
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span att2="sp">
    </span>
<div>
```

***Another option***

```
var temp=$('span[att2="sp"]').first().closest('div[att1="first_div"]');
alert(temp.attr("id"));
```

Comment: tanks for your answer. but your answer is not global answer and it woks just for this example :(.

Comment: Jquery selectors work based on html structure. is your html structure revised?